# How to compile CFugue library on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, vfw

I found a great library: [CFugue](http://gopalakrishna.palem.in/CFugue.html). That's exactly what I need, but I cannot use it on linux. They wrote that it works on ubuntu, but I did not succeed:

g++ said that "vfw.h" doesn't exist. As far as I understand it stands for "video for windows". 
Is it possible to use CFugue on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you because I still haven't been able to get cfugue running on linux either. I emailed the developer and asked him how to do it, he sent these instructions:

1. Go to the downloaded source code 'MusicNote' directory and create a new directory called 'build'
2. cd to the newly created 'build' directory
3. issue the command: 
   cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' ..
4. once done, issue the command 
   make

You should see the line 'Linking CXX executable ../Bin/StaticLibTestAppdu'

If you enter the command '../Bin/StaticLibTestAppdu' it should run.

But it still didn't work for me. These are the last few lines of output from make, I think it means there is a problem with ALSA, but I'm no expert.

```
/home/tom/Workspace/cfuge/CFugue_src_22Jan12/MusicNote/src/MusicNoteLib/MIDIDrivers/AlsaDriver.cpp:167:29: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::fpos<_StateT>’ and ‘std::future_status’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MusicNoteLib.dir/src/MusicNoteLib/MIDIDrivers/AlsaDriver.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MusicNoteLib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I would not be surprised if ALSA is the issue. I remember trying to get FreeTTS to run in java under linux with no luck because the ALSA driver was bad. I first put ubuntu on my laptop in 2008, sound wouldn't work at all. Newer versions work, I think since they made pulseaudio the default. But it still seems like sound drivers for linux are troublesome.

Comment: What version of linux are you using? I have no clue why it worked for you but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume you're trying to build the library using CMake, right?)

That header comes with Wine. Specifically, the development package of Wine. It's usually called "wine-dev" or "wine-devel" on most Linux distros.

Note that CFugue is written in C++11, so you'll need a recent GCC version. 4.7 should work, 4.6 might work, but 4.5 will most probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/cfugue/code/195/)

```
+IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")   # Linux specific code
+     SET(CFugue_Dependencies asound)
+ENDIF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
```

it should support linux build.

Try

> cmake < path to cfugue checkout >
>
> make

Then depending on result restate your question.